# LED glowing letters

Tags: animation, node-editor

Hi im making Signage Letter Glow animation. Letter should emit all RGB light in the shared video. Do i have to assign all the color and key frame or with material it will work. Blinking of the RGB colorful light. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwMEnrVw40U

Answer (score 4):

### Final

[image: final]

### Overview

You can create **Color Ramp** with colors you want to use in animation and control it by **Multiply** node. This will basically increase **Position** over time and choose another color.

[image: Nodes]

Comment: Thanks for replying thats what need. Can you plz explain the below part regarding the dope sheet. Do i have set key frame on each color & White material is transparent. Plz share the file.

Comment: @atek You only need to keyframe Value field. On 1 frame keyframe value 0 and on 200 frame keyframe value 8.36 or something else based on how much colors you will have. I do not have this file, I didn't save it.